# Bingo Board - Methods to interact with (By Highlighting) multiple cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I'm trying to do is make a bingo board that lists the numbers 1 - 75 in one section and either click them, or highlight them manually and then have it review 5 or 6 cards in the same sheet and automatically highlight those corresponding numbers on each of the boards.

Comment: Have you started with anything? I suggest you edit your post with anything you have tried otherwise you are going to get downvoted and no answer.

Answer (score 1):

The SU community is no programming service where you can put your requirements and hope for some solution to pop up. It is meant for users who are stuck or have a specific question. Check [the help section of this site](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for further info about [what (not) to post](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask) (and how to post it).

Just to get you started on your Bingo sheet, I'll give you some hints:

1. As you said, begin by creating a list of numbers and add a `TRUE` or `FALSE` value in the column behind it to indicate if the number is drawn.
2. Create and area where you can enter one or more bingo cards where you can enter in the numbers that are on the actual card(s).
3. Next to each card, create an area the same size as the card and use the `VLOOKUP` function ([Microsoft course on VLOOKUP here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-RZ101862716.aspx?CTT=1)) to lookup the `TRUE`/`FALSE` values of each value from the table you created in step 1.
4. Now you can use [conditional formatting](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Quick-start-Apply-conditional-formatting-6b6f7c2a-5d62-45a1-8f67-584a76776d67?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to color the values in your cards, based on the `TRUE`/`FALSE` values that are next to the chart.
5. To make it all fancy, you can check how many `TRUE`'s there are in each row/column/diagonal using `COUNTIF` ([documentation here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)) and show per

Good luck! And if you're stuck: just comment on this answer and I'll promise to take a look at it.

Comment: Well I wasn't really looking for someone to program it for me, I wanted to see if anyone had any pointers on how to get started. Its not as if excel has a help document on bingo cards on the off chance someone would need to make one. ;) I do definitely appreciate the suggestions.